# PHP Web-Scraping works only in local machine

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have a web scraping developed in PHP using Guzzle and Goutte that reads data from the bet365 site. It runs without any problem in my local environment, but on a internet web host it only works in the first time or second time and then the connection starts to be refused (I received a different message in each server I hosted my app).

1) Why it works in my local machine and not on a internet web host?

2) I've heard the proxy may be an alternative, but how can I find a proxy server to implement in my application? Would I need just one server address or many?

3) Is there any other try to perform to make this works?

One of the messages, but it came from the request, not from my application:
[image]

In another server which I don't have the print any more I received

403 - Forbidden

The Headers I am using in my app:

```
        $headers = array(
        'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/' . rand(0, 9) . '.' . rand(0, 9) . ' (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/' . rand(100, 900) . '.' . rand(10, 90) . ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/' . rand(10, 90) . '.' . rand(0, 9) . '.' . rand(1000, 9000) . '.' . rand(100, 900) . ' Safari/' . rand(100, 900) . '.' . rand(10, 90) . ' OPR/' . rand(10, 90) . '.' . rand(0, 9) . '.' . rand(1000, 9000) . '.' . rand(10, 90)
    );

    //SET Client Request
    $client = new Goutte\Client();
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(
            array(
        'timeout' => 90, 
         'verify' => false,

    ));

    $client->setClient($guzzleClient);
    $client->followRedirects(true);
    if (@$headers['User-Agent'])
        $client->setServerParameter('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $headers['User-Agent']);
    foreach ($headers as $k => $v)
        $client->setHeader($k, $v);
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: they probably dont allow scraping, and are blocking you. perhaps you should respect that

Comment: But why does it work from my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Why it works in my local machine and not on a internet web host?**

> on a internet web host it only works in the first time or second time
>   and then the connection starts to be refused

It works on your local machine because it's coming from your IP address which is a real residential IP address. It's very easy for them to determine a web host IP so that's why it quickly stops working. This is especially true if you use (or re-purchase from another company using) services from a major web host like AWS/Google/etc.

**2) I've heard the proxy may be an alternative, but how can I find a proxy server to implement in my application? Would I need just one server address or many?**

It could work. But you'd probably need many IP addresses if/when the proxy IPs also start to get blocked.

**3) Is there any other try to perform to make this works?**

You're battling with a very big company that I would imagine spends a great deal of time and money to protect its most valuable resource (its website). I don't think you're going to win this battle.

If you need to scrape a bit of data I'd suggest you just leave it running on your local machine (or setup a small server on your local network).